# vscode issue while debug Rust

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust

I have a very simple [Rust sample](https://github.com/r0bbar/sample_rust_kafka) (Github repo [here](https://github.com/r0bbar/sample_rust_kafka)) which uses [Kafka](https://github.com/kafka-rust/kafka-rust) module

My vscode **launch.json** is like this:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug executable 'rust_kafka'",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/target/debug/rust_kafka.exe",
            "cargo": {
                "args": [
                    "build",
                    "--bin=rust_kafka",
                    "--package=rust_kafka"
                ],
                "filter": {
                    "name": "rust_kafka",
                    "kind": "bin"
                }
            },
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "env": {
                "PATH": "${env:USERPROFILE}\\.cargo\\registry\\cache\\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f;${env:PATH}"
            }            
        },
        {
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug unit tests in executable 'rust_kafka'",
            "cargo": {
                "args": [
                    "test",
                    "--no-run",
                    "--bin=rust_kafka",
                    "--package=rust_kafka"
                ],
                "filter": {
                    "name": "rust_kafka",
                    "kind": "bin"
                }
            },
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I started out, I can hit F5 on vscode, put a break point at println statement below, and was able to hit that breakpoint after I hit F5:

```
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, Kafka Rust!");
}
```

All good up to this point.

Then I added Kafka (Of course rebuild: cargo build), when hit F5 on vscode. After that it's say **"Unknown error"** and prompted to **"Open launch.json"**:

```
extern crate kafka;

use kafka::producer::{Producer, Record};

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, Kafka Rust!"); // I cannot even hit break point in first line of program
    let hosts = vec!["localhost:9092".to_owned(), "localhost:9093".to_owned(), "localhost:9094".to_owned()];

    let mut _producer = Producer::from_hosts(hosts).create().unwrap();

    for i in 0..10 {
        let buf = format!("{i}");
        match _producer.send(&Record::from_value("topic-name", buf.as_bytes())) {
            Ok(()) => {
                println!("Great! message {} sent!", i);
            }
            Err(error) => {
                eprintln!("Error sending message: {}", error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

I know it is Kafka runtime issue, but **question is** to Code Team:

1. why the first println breakpoint wasn't hit
   AND
2. vscode complained about launch.json? That comes before any Kafka calls.

[image]

Anyway, I manually created the topic, I was able to **"cargo run"** the Rust script (But still stuck same issue with VSCode that after I hit F5, still doesn't hit breakpoint first line of script and complained about launch.json):

```
C:\kafka\kafka_2.13-2.7.0\bin\windows>kafka-topics.bat --create --topic some-topic --bootstrap-server localhost:9092,localhost:9093,localhost:9094
Created topic some-topic.
```

See? **cargo run** successfully.
[image]

I also tried separate Kafka references into separate module, didn't help. VSCode is just refusing to let me debug it.